Creating Teams Calendar Events that Sync With Outlook
I'm currently working through a problem trying to copy MS Bookings sessions over to a Team Calendar. The events are syncing fine within Outlook but not routing up to the Team Calendar. It appears the Team calendar only shows invite created from that Team. The ask is if there is a way I can have a calendar in Teams that will show appointments from multiple users. If not, is there a way I can spoof creating an event using the Team and assigning it to the Channel. We can create them within Teams, but I'm looking for automation using either Graph calls or Power Automate.
I'm looking through various Graph calls and ootb connectors within Power Automate and nothing is coming up that will help me create a calendar invite for a channel. The Email has a calendar that events are syncing to, but can't find a way to display this calendar within Teams.

Currently it is not supported to create event/meeting and assign it to channel.
